# How can I change the first element of a list?

Tags: python, list, arraylist, python-itertools

I have this list of elements:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2]]
```

and I would like to increase it like this:

```
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1].................] then with 2:

[[2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1].................] and so on until 5.
```

I dont want to hard code so I was trying itertools but I could only reach up to 2 like this:

```
first2 = list(map(list, itertools.product(list(range(3)), repeat = 3)))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What does your code have to do with incrementing the first element of each nested list?

Comment: its for coordinates, I am trying to build a rubik's cube.

Comment: Why up to 5? (Just curious, I'm a cuber, and Rubik's cube is 3x3x3.)

Comment: @KellyBundy left, right, front, back, up and down. First time doing a rubik's cube solver and it was the first idea I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.product()` to create the 2nd and 3rd elements, and an outer loop to prepend 0 through 5 to them.

```
result = []
for i in range(6):
    result.extend([i] + list(x) for x in itertools.product(range(3), repeat = 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "dont want to hard code".

Can't you just do something like this?

```
for _ in range(5):
    for item in mylist:
        item[0] += 1
```

Comment: Based on the code he posted, I think what he actually wants is for all these lists to be concatenated. `itertools.product()` won't use a different range for the first element than the other 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 2],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 1],
    [0, 2, 2],
]

out = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    out.append([[i, *subl[1:]] for subl in lst])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    [
        [1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 2],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 0],
        [1, 2, 1],
        [1, 2, 2],
    ],
    [
        [2, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 1],
        [2, 0, 2],
...
```

---

One-liner:

```py
out = [[[i, *subl[1:]] for subl in lst] for i in range(1, 6)]
print(out)
```